# Extract (parse) amount and description from BIZ (Transaction) sms

Tags: android, parsing, sms, inbox

I am doing below steps.

1. match sms with regex
2. if contains specified keyword then get values from sms body like **amount,description (reason of transaction), Account number(if ATM withdraw),transaction type(debit/credit)**

   this regex not matching all kind of bank/transaction sms thus it is not efficient , is there any other way to identify bank message.

example sms :

1) Dear Customer, your Account Number **XXXXXX6377** has been **credited** by **Rs            215.000** being DBT/DBTL funds transfer on 19/05/2015 - CENTRAL BANK OF INDIA

2)A/c NN5715 **debited** for **Rs 2000**; ATM WDL. A/c Bal(sub to chq realisatn) Rs13286.23 on 24APR 21:19hr. Call 1800226999 to block your card if not used by you.

3) Dear Customer, Your Ac **XXXXXXXX5666** is **credited** with **INR8,922.00** on 16 Feb. Info. INF*000080483346*SALARY. Your Net Available Bal is INR 8,922.00.

```
private static ArrayList<SmsDto> parsevalues(ArrayList<SmsDto> body_val) {
    ArrayList<SmsDto> resSms = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < body_val.size(); i++) {
        SmsDto smsDto = body_val.get(i);
        Pattern regEx
                = Pattern.compile("(?:inr|rs)+[\\s]*[0-9+[\\,]*+[0-9]*]+[\\.]*[0-9]+");
        // Find instance of pattern matches
        Matcher m = regEx.matcher(smsDto.getBody());
        if (m.find()) {
            try {
                Log.e("amount_value= ", "" + m.group(0));
                String amount = (m.group(0).replaceAll("inr", ""));
                amount = amount.replaceAll("rs", "");
                amount = amount.replaceAll("inr", "");
                amount = amount.replaceAll(" ", "");
                amount = amount.replaceAll(",", "");
                smsDto.setAmount(Double.valueOf(amount));
                if (smsDto.getBody().contains("debited") ||
                        smsDto.getBody().contains("purchasing") || smsDto.getBody().contains("purchase") || smsDto.getBody().contains("dr")) {
                    smsDto.setTransactionType("0");
                } else if (smsDto.getBody().contains("credited") || smsDto.getBody().contains("cr")) {
                    smsDto.setTransactionType("1");
                }
                smsDto.setParsed("1");
                Log.e("matchedValue= ", "" + amount);
                if (!Character.isDigit(smsDto.getSenderid().charAt(0)))
                    resSms.add(smsDto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("No_matchedValue ", "No_matchedValue ");
        }
    }
    return resSms;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

For finding out amount from bank transaction message.

```
(?i)(?:(?:RS|INR|MRP)\.?\s?)(\d+(:?\,\d+)?(\,\d+)?(\.\d{1,2})?)
```

For finding out merchant name from bank transaction message.

```
(?i)(?:\sat\s|in\*)([A-Za-z0-9]*\s?-?\s?[A-Za-z0-9]*\s?-?\.?)
```

For finding out card name(debit/credit card) from bank transaction message.

```
(?i)(?:\smade on|ur|made a\s|in\*)([A-Za-z]*\s?-?\s[A-Za-z]*\s?-?\s[A-Za-z]*\s?-?)
```

Comment: Its works for me to fetch amount from bank message. But now I want to find name of account from which my amount gets credited/Debited.
eg : my message is like "Thank you for using Debit Card ending with 1001 for Rs.2500.00 in MUMBAI at ADITYA BIRLA FASHION on 2017-02-20."

Now i want to fetch "ADITYA BIRLA FASHION" from bank messages. so how to do that?

Comment: @priyankakamthe : You can use this pattern for your message : (?i)(?:\sat\s|in|on\*)([A-Za-z0-9]*\s?-?\s?[A-Za-z0-9]*\s?-?\.?)

Comment: @VikalpPatel this regx works for those message which having **at** or **in** or **on** . But what if message contains other than this. Like  :
"Dear Customer, You have made a Debit Card purchase of INR1,600.00 on 30 Jan. Info.VPS*AGGARWAL SH. "

Comment: @priyankaKamthe were you able to find out a fix which covers all these cases?

Answer (score 3):

In python following Regex can be helpful.

For finding amount in bank messages

```
[rR][sS]\.?\s[,\d]+\.?\d{0,2}|[iI][nN][rR]\.?\s*[,\d]+\.?\d{0,2}
```

For finding A/C no

```
[0-9]*[Xx\*]*[0-9]*[Xx\*]+[0-9]{3,}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following two regular expressions helped in finding amount from most of the bank transactions(HDFC, ICICI, ING, KOTAK, SBI, CANARA, PNB):

```
[Ii][Nn][Rr](\\s*.\\s*\\d*)
[rR][sS](\\s*.\\s*\\d*)
```

Please comment if you have figured out much better expressions than the above.

Comment: thanks for answer is these regx will gives transaction separate info

Comment: thanks but I get only first Digit of amount using  [Ii][Nn][Rr](\\s*.\\s*\\d*) reguler expression.how can i get all digits

Answer (score 2):

Please Check in this link:-https://github.com/vikashstm/transactionsmsfilter
Here maximum , banking filter added.

It has also get through message:-

1. Deducted Amount,
2. balance message identified and get available message
3. Account Number
4. Transaction Mode
5. Reference Number/transaction Information etc...

Answer (score 1):

To detect any transactional message in android :

```
"(?=.*[Aa]ccount.*|.*[Aa]/[Cc].*|.*[Aa][Cc][Cc][Tt].*|.*[Cc][Aa][Rr][Dd].*)(?=.*[Cc]redit.*|.*[Dd]ebit.*)(?=.*[Ii][Nn][Rr].*|.*[Rr][Ss].*)"
```

tested on several bank messages

Comment: This is giving me promotional messages also. Is there any alternative to find out only credit card and debit card transactions?

Comment: try including more words like Transaction,Amount..This regex was working fine for me.Try to figure out why that promotional message is filtering out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny

Usage:

```js
import { getTransactionInfo } from "trny";

const message = "Your a/c XX0413 is debited on 15/12/2020 by INR 3,211.00 towards purchase. Avl Bal: INR 5,603.54.";

const info = getTransactionInfo(message);
 
/* 
info = {     
   account: {
    type: "account",
    no: "0413"
   },
   balance: "5603.54",
   money: "3211.00",
   typeOfTransaction: "debited" 
}
*/
```

It also has methods like

1. [getAccount](https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny#getaccount)
2. [getMoneySpent](https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny#getmoneyspent)
3. [getBalance](https://github.com/minimal-scouser/trny#getbalance)

This needs more testing but see if this solves your problem.