# Extract amount and other information from text in Swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

I am trying to extract following information :

- Complete account number as in the paragraph (XXXXXXXXXX1234)
- Amount
- Info
- Date

from the following text :

```
Dear Customer, Thank you for banking with ABC Bank. You have used your Debit Card linked to Account XXXXXXXX1234 for a transaction of INR 404.00 Info.MIN*ABC on 15-08-2012 11:58:41.
```

I tried using the regular expression answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37409435/940549), but with no luck. The following is the code i am trying :

```
let regex = NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: "\d\d?:\d\d", options: nil)
```

But getting error as "Invalid escape sequence in literal". Thanks for any help.

Comment: Give us some code, like what you have tried. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you in drafting a question. And remember, SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: And please never paste code as image.

Comment: Use double backslashes - `"\\d\\d?:\\d\\d"`, but it will get you `11:58` only. Any other, *real* issues?