# Which way is it better to extract Account number and Balance from a SMS body?

Tags: java, android, performance, parsing, sms

I am planning a task to read all the Bank related SMS from the users android mobile inbox and extract their account number and balance from it. I am guessing this could be done in 2 ways as,

> 1. Using RegEx to extract the data from the SMS body as stated [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068134/extract-parse-amount-and-description-from-biz-transaction-sms). This certainly has the advantage of giving generic representation of any Bank Balance message
> 2. Store a template message of every bank in the database and compare it with the read SMS to extract the data

I would like to know which path is efficient or Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Thank you for quick and clear response @GhostCat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two approaches have different qualities:

- Option 1 might lead to many different, **complex** regular expressions. Alone glancing into the answer you linked made my head spin. Meaning: **maintaining** such a list of regular expressions will not be an easy undertaking from the developer perspective.
- Whereas for option 2, of course you have to keep track regarding your collection of "templates", but: once your infrastructure is in place, the only work required for you: adding new templates; or adapting them.

So, from a "development" efforts side I would tend to option 2 --- because such "templates" are easier to manage by you. You don't even need much understanding of the Java language in order to deal with such templates. They are just text; containing some defined **keywords** here and there. 
One could even think about telling your users how to define templates **themselves**! They know how the SMS from *their* bank looks like; so you could think about some "import" mechanism where your APP pulls the SMS text, and then the user tells the APP (once) where the relevant parts can be found in there!

Regarding runtime efficiency: I wouldn't rely on people making guesses here. Instead: make experiments with real world data; and see if matching SMS text against a larger set of complex regular expressions is cheaper or more expensive than matching them against much simpler "templates".

Answer (score 2):

1. Storing the template for each bank cost more memory (if you load them on at start up for efficiency) and file system storage, and also as you stated, there is the downside of requiring previous know each bank template and setup the user application properly to it.
2. Using the regex will not cost file system store neither more memory, however it could create false positives for something which looks like a bank message, but it is not. However there is the facility to not need to know all the banks out there in order to do it properly.